# How to make the function Global in Codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to make the function global in CodeIgniter application. I have created a PHP file `Constant.php`  in `application/libraries`.

Constant.php

```
<?php 

 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Constant
 {

public function custom_number_format($n, $precision = 1) {
if ($n < 900) {
    // 0 - 900
    $n_format = number_format($n, $precision);
    $suffix = '';
} else if ($n < 900000) {
    // 0.9k-850k
    $n_format = number_format($n / 1000, $precision);
    $suffix = 'K';
} else if ($n < 900000000) {
    // 0.9m-850m
    $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000, $precision);
    $suffix = 'M';
} else if ($n < 900000000000) {
    // 0.9b-850b
    $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000000, $precision);
    $suffix = 'B';
} else {
    // 0.9t+
    $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000000000, $precision);
    $suffix = 'T';
}
 // Remove unecessary zeroes after decimal. "1.0" -> "1"; "1.00" -> "1"
 // Intentionally does not affect partials, eg "1.50" -> "1.50"
if ( $precision > 0 ) {
    $dotzero = '.' . str_repeat( '0', $precision );
    $n_format = str_replace( $dotzero, '', $n_format );
}
return $n_format . $suffix;
 }

 }
```

I have declared this library in the `config/autoload.php` something like

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('constant');
```

and now I trying to access this library something like

```
$totalview=$this->Constant->custom_number_format($views);
```

But I am getting the following error 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried manually loading it from your file like `$this->load->library('constant');` ?

Comment: try with the helper so no need to add class name always before calling any function in MVC, helper will be easy than a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure, but I think you should call as declared.

If you declared it as:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('constant');
```

You should call it as:

```
$totalview=$this->constant->custom_number_format($views);
```

(with lowercase).